# Php on zend, how to escape a variable for a query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-injection

im doing some queries in Zend Framework and i need to make sure no SQL injection is possible in the next kind of formats. I can use mysql_escape(deprecated) and wont do all the work. If i try to use real_mysql_escape it wont be able to grab the conection with the database and i cant find how zend_filter would solve the problem.

The query im doing (simplied) have the next sintaxes:

```
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db'); 
    $select = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
                FROM message m
                WHERE m.message LIKE '".$username." %'";
    $row = $db->fetchRow($select);
```

What is the best way to prevent SQL INJECTION with this framework?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Easy:

```
$db->quote($username);
```

So:

```
   $username = $db->quote($username . '%');
   $select = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
                                FROM message m
                                WHERE m.message LIKE ' . $username;
   $row = $db->fetchRow($select);
```

Comment: when I use $db->quote on a string that I am inserting, it puts quotes into the string even in the database field. Do I have to trim it after i quote it, or am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 14):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username LIKE ?';
$row = $db->fetchRow($sql, $username);
```

**Reference**: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html

Comment: The % is missing in this example, could it work suffixing $username with '%'?

Answer (score 1):

When working with a model you can use:

```
$bugs = new Bugs();
$row = $bugs->fetchRow($bugs->select()->where('bug_id = ?', 1));
```